# How can i pass string to string[]?

Tags: c#

I need to pass a string with type A,B,C,D,E(Separated with comma) in each string[] value.

```
String Test ="A,B,C,D,E";
string[] arr1 = new string[5];
```

Comment: Do you want each item in `arr1` to be `A,B,C,D,E`, or do you want arr1 to be `A,B,C,D,E` separated in items of the array?

Comment: @theMayer Similar method, different language

Comment: @theMayer Why did you mark as a duplicate of an javascript question?

Comment: Well, the syntax is the same, the purpose is the same, and a reasonable person should be able to make an inference as to the behavior.

Comment: if only that were true

Comment: @theMayer You are assuming too much.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson - no, I don’t think so. This is not a site for folks who haven’t even done a modicum of research to show up and create spam. So an assumption of “a reasonable person” is indeed appropriate.

Comment: @theMayer While I agree with you about the "not a site for folks who haven't done a modicum of research", I still don't agree with marking as a duplicate when the duplicate is in another programming language. I agree that the syntax is similar, but there are some differences between C# and javascript when it comes to the Split() method, as C# has 6 overloaded versions of the method. Also, my original comment was in jest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .Split()

```
string[] arr1 = Test.Split(',');
```

Comment: So Quick answer thank you!

Comment: What if i want to convert in int array?  int[] arr2 = Convert.ToInt32(TEst.Split(',')); I get error cant convert from int[] to int32

Comment: Use linq, int[] arr2 = Test.Split(',').Select(x => System.Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray(); of course this won't work since you have letters and not integer numbers represented by string values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert this string into a `string[]` with size 5:

```
string[] arr1 = Enumerable.Repeat(Test, 5).ToArray();
```

of course the classic way is to use a for-loop:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[5];
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    arr1[i] = "A,B,C,D,E";
```

If you instead want to create a `string[]` from the string:

```
string[] arr1 = "A,B,C,D,E".Split(',');
```